# Merge spark dataframe by row

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two spark dataframe:

**df1**

```
+------+--------------------+
|   id |            feature |           
+------+--------------------+
|     1|                 aaa|
+------+--------------------+
```

**df2**

```
+------+--------------------+
|   id |            feature |           
+------+--------------------+
|     2|                 bbb|
+------+--------------------+
```

Now I want to merge df1 and df2 into:

```
+------+--------------------+
|   id |            feature |           
+------+--------------------+
|     1|                 aaa|
+------+--------------------+
|     2|                 bbb|
+------+--------------------+
```

How could I do?

Comment: simply do df1.union(df2) ...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `df1.unionall(df2)` for merging these 2 dataframes row by row.

Comment: `unionall` does not exist. There is `unionAll` which is deprecated, you should just use `union` or `unionByName`

Comment: true..!! unionall is deprecated for spark 2.0 and unionByName works starting from spark 2.3+.

Answer (score 2):

If that's the case, same columns both dataframe, just union them

```
df1.union(df2)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df1.unionByName(df2)
```

UnionByName function : [https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#unionByName(other:org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[T]):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[T]](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#unionByName(other:org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset%5BT%5D):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset%5BT%5D)